# derivative of expectation of an integral process

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, continuity, compactness

Let

- $E$ be a topological space with $\{x\}\in\mathcal B(E)$ for all $x\in E$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $x\in E$
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $E$-valued product measurable process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with $$\operatorname P[X_0=x]=1$$
- $c:E\to[0,\infty)$ be Borel measurable and continuous at $x$

Assume $X(\omega)$ and hence $(c\circ X)(\omega)$ is right-continuous at $0$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$.

Let $$A_t:=\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$ We easily see that $A(\omega)$ is right-differentiable at $0$ with $$\left.\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}A_t(\omega)\right|_{t=0+}=c(x)\tag1$$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$. Thus, $$M_t:=e^{-A_t}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is right-differentiable at $0$ with $$\left.\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}M_t(\omega)\right|_{t=0+}=-c(x)\tag2$$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$.

> Are we able to show that $$\frac{\operatorname E[M_t-M_0]}t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}-c(x)\tag3?$$

Comment: If $f$ is continuous then $c\circ f$ is bouned on $[0,t_0]$.

Comment: I think you are a bit too optimistic here. Suppose for simplicity that $E$ is the real line and let $c(x)=|x|$. If $c(X_t)\leq Z$ for all $t\in(0,t_0)$ where $t_0>0$ and $Z\in\mathcal{L}^1(P)$ then, in particular, you have $X_{t_0}\in\mathcal{L}^1(P)$. Not all $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ will satisfy this.

Comment: @jakobdt You are absolutely right. What I actually want to find is to show that $$Y_t:=\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is differentiable at $0$ with derivative $c(X_0)$. If the claim in this question would hold, then we could show this using Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. I would ask a different question and delete this one, but do you see any chance to show this at all?

Comment: @jakobdt Ah, but I was too hasty. $X_t\in\mathcal L^1(\operatorname P)$ for all $t\ge0$ is an assumption I'm willing to admit.

Comment: Hmm... Suppose instead that $c(x)=x^2$. Then you need to assume that $X_{t_0}$ has second moment to get what you initially asked for.

Comment: @jakobdt Yes, that will not help at all. But what do you think about the differentiability of $Y_t$ at $0$?

Comment: Do you not have differentiability for any fixed $\omega\in\Omega$?

Comment: @jakobdt Yes, sorry. What I mean is that I want to conclude differentiability of $t\mapsto\operatorname E[Y_t]$. And I guess we need Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem for that. (Or can we use the monotone convergence theorem instead?)

Comment: For the monotone convergence I don't think there is a way to ensure that the difference quotient converges to the derivative of $Y_t$ at $0$ in a monotone way. Also, it is not obvious to me that $t\mapsto E[Y_t]$ should be differentiable. For example, can you be sure that $E[Y_t]$ exists?

Comment: @jakobdt Please take note of my edit.

Comment: I agree with your calculations, but I do not see how you conclude (1). Also, what do you do when $E[Y_t]$ is infinite?

Comment: @jakobdt Why should that be a problem? The monotone convergence theorem also applies for $[0,\infty]$-valued random variables.

Comment: @jakobdt From $(2)$, $(4)$ and $(5)$, we immediately obtain $(1)$, don't we?

Comment: You need to let $t\to0+$ and $n\to\infty$ *simultaneously* so (1) does not come immediately. And yes, the monotone convergence theorem still works. I was thinking more about the difference quotient $E[Y_t]/t$ which might be infinite. Somehow this should converge to $E[Z_0]$ (which I guess you assume is finite?).

Comment: @jakobdt Yes, simultaneously, but that shouldn't be a problem or am I missing something? I don't think that we need to assume $\operatorname E[Z_0]<\infty$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Theorem_3.

Comment: @jakobdt However, I've made a mistake in formulating what I'm actually trying to show. So, I've edited the question once again.

Comment: The simultaneous convergence is not trivial. I suggest you try to prove it, and then you will see that it is not so simple.

Comment: @jakobdt It is not that important anymore, since this attempt is not applicable to the new version of the question ... Now I guess we need to use some fact about the growth of the exponential.

Comment: Can you use the fact that $0\leq M_t\leq 1$ for all $t\geq0$?

Comment: @jakobdt I don't know *how*, since $\frac1tM_t$ could still be unbounded.